# ASP.NET RDLC: Display field from another table in tablix

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dataset, rdlc

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 project with EF. I have a ASPX Web Page to display a ReportControl for RDLC reports.

There I have 2 tables : **Orders** and **Agents**. In my report I want to display (in a Tablix) all my orders.

**OrderNo  |  OrderDate  |  OrderTotal  |  OrderStatus  | Agent**

(Agent column is the name of the agent : "Agent.Name")

**Q :** How can I display a field(Agent.Name) from another table(Agent) in a Tablix?

```
if (!IsPostBack)
   {
    var qry = FROM o in db.Orders
              //JOIN a in d.Agents on o.idAgent equals a.idAgent
              SELECT o; // 
    ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSetOrder_Agent", qry);
    ReportViewerOrders.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using SP:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].spAgentOrders    
   (
   @fromdate DATE,
   @todate DATE
   )   
   AS
   DECLARE @from DATE = @fromdate, @to DATE = @todate
   SELECT o.orderbo, o.orderdate, o.ordervalue, o.status, a.name
   FROM orders o 
   JOIN agent a on o.id_agent = a.id_agent
   WHERE o.orderdate between @from and @to
   RETURN
   ```

Update the Model, add the SP as a Function Import that returns a complex type.
2. Webform codebehind:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
//...
var qry = db.spAgentOrders(tbFrom.Text, tbTo.Text);

ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSetOrder_Agent", qry);
ReportViewerOrders.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
}
```

1. Update the report's DataSource .xsd. Drag the SP from Server Explorer.